# Splitting a very long word into several lines without using the \seqsplit package

Tags: line-breaking

I have a very long word (in a table tabular) that needs to be split up into several lines by using to the page margins. Normally I would use the advice given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13677/splitting-very-big-numbers-over-several-lines) and elsewhere but my word contains some Unicode characters and therefore I cannot use the \seqsplit package. Is there any similar package that I can use which does the job for me?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hhline}

\begin{document}

\noindent \begin{tabular} {|c|c|}

\hline
Text no & Text \\ \hline
1 & AAEFPIOJEOJWOIJIOJWFJOWEIJOWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGERGÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOERGERGWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJERGERGERGERGERGFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGERGÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOERGERGWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJERGERGERGERGERGFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGERGÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOERGERGWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJERGERGERGERGERGFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGERGÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOERGERGWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJERGERGERGERGERGFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGERGÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOERGERGWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJERGERGERGERGERGFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGERGÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOERGERGWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJERGERGERGERGERGFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGERGÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOERGERGWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJERGERGERGERGERGFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGERGÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOERGERGWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJERGERGERGERGERGFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGERGÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOERGERGWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJERGERGERGERGERGFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGERGÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOERGERGWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJERGERGERGERGERGFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGERGÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOERGERGWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJERGERGERGERGERGFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGERGÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOERGERGWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJERGERGERGERGERGFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGERGÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOERGERGWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJERGERGERGERGERGFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGERGÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOERGERGWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJERGERGERGERGERGFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGERGÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOERGERGWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJERGERGERGERGERGFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGERGÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOERGERGWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJERGERGERGERGERGFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGERGÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOERGERGWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJERGERGERGERGERGFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGERGÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOERGERGWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJERGERGERGERGERGFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGERGÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOERGERGWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJERGERGERGERGERGFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGERGÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOERGERGWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJERGERGERGERGERGFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGERGÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOERGERGWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJERGERGERGERGERGFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGERGÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOERGERGWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJERGERGERGERGERGFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGERGÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOERGERGWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJERGERGERGERGERGFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGERGÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOERGERGWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJERGERGERGERGERGFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGERGÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOERGERGWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJERGERGERGERGERGFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖERGERGERGERGÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWETHYRHRTHRTHIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWERREGREGEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJERGERGERGFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFERGERGEERGERGJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEERGERGERGERGEGIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOERGERGERGJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEGERGERGERGFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖRGERGERGERGERÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFERHTERGERGJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWERGERGERGERGEGIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄ
\end{tabular} \\ \vskip .5cm

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please always include a complete document that shows the problem, we are missing several details: pdlfatex or xetex or luatex (for unicode text)? automatic breaking or manual required? hyphenation required?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I don't know what xetex and those are. I write my code on writelatex.com. The Unicode package is utf8, which is incompatible with seqsplit. Automatic breaking is required since it is too difficult to do by hand and I have a lot of words like that.

Comment: No please don't do `%The rest of the "word" goes on for a long time.` that negates the point of the example, which is to allow people to test their answers. the word should be long, and since you say it includes problem characters it should include those.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle No, I am not going to post the entire word here, it contains private information. I cannot possibly see how that is necessary, just imagine that it contains maybe an additional thousand or so random characters.

Comment: We don't care what the word is, just make up some arbitrary string _that demonstrates the problem_

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Okay this almost crashed my browser but I hope this is enough.

Comment: Do you need a table? Or may be a list serves you as well? By the way, that code you posted doesn't break well even if it's outside tabular. So, for me (not a TeXpert), there are two problems: how to show a long word (such long word) in an acceptable way; and second, put it in a tabular.

Comment: @Manuel A table would probably be best, but I am mostly looking for an organized representation of this word and a few others that are of similar length while also identifying them with a few properties. It is maybe best not to think of it as a word but instead as a long letter sequence.

Comment: But then you should really explain what your problem is: what rules do you expect where the word es broken, do you need a hyphen? I mean, *we need to know* in order to help. [May be…](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-does-xy-problem-mean)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

A `c` column never linebreaks, changing it to `p` solves most of the cases but some lines are overfull if you use English hyphenation, so this inserts some extra hyphenation points.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hhline}

\makeatletter
\def\x#1{\-#1\x}


\def\xx{%
\raggedright
\def\UTFviii@two@octets##1\x##2{\expandafter
    \UTFviii@defined\csname u8:##1\string##2\endcsname\x}%
\def\UTFviii@three@octets##1\x##2##3{\expandafter
    \UTFviii@defined\csname u8:##1\string##2\string##3\endcsname\x}
\def\stopx\x{}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{flushright}
\begin{tabular} {|c|p{.7\textwidth}|}

\hline
Text no & Text \\ \hline
1 & \xx\x AAEFPIOJEOJWOIJIOJWFJOWEIJOWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGERGÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOERGERGWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJERGERGERGERGERGFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGERGÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOERGERGWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJERGERGERGERGERGFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGERGÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOERGERGWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJERGERGERGERGERGFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGERGÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOERGERGWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJERGERGERGERGERGFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGERGÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOERGERGWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJERGERGERGERGERGFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGERGÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOERGERGWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJERGERGERGERGERGFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGERGÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOERGERGWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJERGERGERGERGERGFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGERGÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOERGERGWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJERGERGERGERGERGFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGERGÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOERGERGWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJERGERGERGERGERGFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGERGÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOERGERGWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJERGERGERGERGERGFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGERGÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOERGERGWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJERGERGERGERGERGFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGERGÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOERGERGWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJERGERGERGERGERGFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGERGÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOERGERGWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJERGERGERGERGERGFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGERGÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOERGERGWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJERGERGERGERGERGFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGERGÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOERGERGWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJERGERGERGERGERGFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGERGÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOERGERGWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJERGERGERGERGERGFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGERGÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOERGERGWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJERGERGERGERGERGFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGERGÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOERGERGWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJERGERGERGERGERGFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGERGÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOERGERGWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJERGERGERGERGERGFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGERGÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOERGERGWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJERGERGERGERGERGFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGERGÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOERGERGWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJERGERGERGERGERGFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGERGÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOERGERGWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJERGERGERGERGERGFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGERGÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOERGERGWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJERGERGERGERGERGFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGERGÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOERGERGWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJERGERGERGERGERGFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGERGÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOERGERGWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJERGERGERGERGERGFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖERGERGERGERGÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWETHYRHRTHRTHIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWERREGREGEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJERGERGERGFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFERGERGEERGERGJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄ\stopx
\end{tabular} 
\end{flushright}
%\\ dont use \\ at end of paragraph 

%\vskip .5cm% not a latex command

\end{document}
```

---

or a 2 row `longtable` to allow page breaking between rows.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hhline,longtable,array}

\makeatletter
\def\x#1{\-#1\x}


\def\xx{%
\raggedright\arraybackslash
\def\UTFviii@two@octets##1\x##2{\expandafter
    \UTFviii@defined\csname u8:##1\string##2\endcsname\x}%
\def\UTFviii@three@octets##1\x##2##3{\expandafter
    \UTFviii@defined\csname u8:##1\string##2\string##3\endcsname\x}
\def\stopx\x{}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}


\begin{longtable}[r] {@{}|c|p{.7\textwidth}|@{}}

\hline
Text no & Text \\ \hline
1 & \xx\x AAEFPIOJEOJWOIJIOJWFJOWEIJOWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGERGÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOERGERGWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJERGERGERGERGERGFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGERGÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOERGERGWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJERGERGERGERGERGFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGERGÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOERGERGWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJERGERGERGERGERGFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGERGÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOERGERGWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJERGERGERGERGERGFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGERGÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOERGERGWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJERGERGERGERGERGFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGERGÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOERGERGWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFIFJOERGERGWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJERGERGERGERGERGFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOEJFOWEIF\stopx \\
2& \xx\x JOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGEÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGERGÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOERGERGWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJERGERGERGERGERGFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGERGÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOERGERGWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJERGERGERGERGERGFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGERGÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOERGERGWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJERGERGERGERGERGFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGERGÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOERGERGWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJERGERGERGERGERGFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖERGERGERGERGERGÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOERGERGWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJERGERGERGERGERGFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWEIFJOWIEFÖÖÖÖÄWEIFJOWIEJFOWEIFJOWE\stopx
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You probably want `\raggedright\arraybackslash` rather than just `\raggedright` so it works in cells ending with `\\ ` as well as `\end{tabular}`

Comment: I get an error (undefined control sequence) on the "1 & \xx\x" line if I make that change. Right now I am trying to make this code work with more values in the table, but adding the line "2 & \xx\x %longword \stopx" returns the error "extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr".

Comment: @Sid no reason why it shouldn't work, hang on I'll shorten the word and try a 2 line table

Comment: @Sid sorry `\arraybackslash` needs `array` package, but see updated answer

Comment: Great, that's well done thank you. The code you just added for a 2-row longtable doesn't compile like this though but it is easily fixable by inserting "\stopx \\" at line 28. This looks almost perfect (especially after inserting two \hline) but is there any way to put "text" at the center of the cell?

Comment: @Sid oops It was working but the system complained my answer was too long so I deleted some bits, must have accidentally zapped the terminator:-) I''l put it back use \centering to center

Comment: I tried \centering but I get a "misplaced \noalign" compile error, I don't know where \noalign comes from.

Comment: @Sid `\centering\arraybackslash` or use `\tabularnewline` instead of `\\ ` to end the table rows