# Line wrapping not working in tabular with long numbers

Tags: tables, line-breaking

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\caption{Results.}\label{tab1}
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{0.5cm}|}
\hline
N & KS & g & n & C & $\lambda(n)$ & $\mu$ & R\\
\hline
1 &
 32 &
 1572324240 &
 1572324239 &
 943290716551438163 &
 1572244920 &
 1470930645&6\\
\hline
2 &
 64 &
 4159540661949250490 &
 4159540661949250489 &
 14726610731536157220276939497631624989 &
 4159171243689855120&3091093397568475626 &
 6\\
\hline
3 &
 96 &
 17921013728107489666861417152 &
 17921013728107489666861417151 &
 319644167630919465013897831470640254404402368723868992349 &
 17918883386300536523002183680&
 8310947063368032641748342092 &
 6\\
\hline
4 &
 128 &
 10960388158297871697330151881871037028 &
 10960388158297871697330151881871037027 &
 106925141663462215096945420078312037311355711106757002541655645931678791491 &
 10958297067198453652392990431562024960 & 
 3253082388973481812242917579299455335 &
 6\\ 
\hline
5 &
 160 &
 11181085000393941012433719385538976929750386340 &
 11181085000393941012433719385538976929750386339 &
 79684675709633819762973841355295907051437943828599200481216296703376032895835669790667255501 &
 11178266769966960229108283302064411639808000000 &
 4208406996756154635702287087616339813762920102 &
 6\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: See this thread : https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2441/121944

Comment: The problem is, that TeX doesn't find any break points in your cells, since line wrapping in a number is not allowed. If you specify break points (or use different cell content, that includes breakpoints) the contents will be wrapped.

Comment: I tried all type of cells p,m,b,l,c,r but its not working. need something auto kind as in HTML

Comment: @yogesh as I wrote the problem lies in the specific contents you have. And a table with such long numbers wouldn't be very comprehensible either. Is the posted content your real use case? Do the numbers have to be precise to the last digit, or is shortening like 1.09e15 viable?

Comment: @Skillmon I got your point, but I need all numbers to be printed, is there any way to typecast numbers to text

Comment: @yogesh I'll try some things.

Comment: Have you tried `seqsplit`? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13688/121944

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I defined a new column type, which introduces a valid break point after each token in a cell. Funny enough this is very similar to an answer provided in the link AML posted (that I've seen after writing the code):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{collcell}

\newcolumntype{N}[1]{>{\collectcell\everytokenbreak}p{#1}<{\endcollectcell}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\everytokenbreak[1]
  {%
    \everytokenbreak@#1&%
  }
\long\def\everytokenbreak@#1%
  {%
    \ifx&#1
    \else
      #1\hspace{0pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}%
      \expandafter\everytokenbreak@
    \fi
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\caption{Results.}\label{tab1}
\begin{tabular}{|N{0.5cm}|N{0.5cm}|N{2cm}|N{2cm}|N{2cm}|N{2cm}|N{2cm}|N{0.5cm}|}
\hline
N & KS & g & n & C & $\lambda(n)$ & $\mu$ & R\\
\hline
1 &
 32 &
 1572324240 &
 1572324239 &
 943290716551438163 &
 1572244920 &
 1470930645&6\\
\hline
2 &
 64 &
 4159540661949250490 &
 4159540661949250489 &
 14726610731536157220276939497631624989 &
 4159171243689855120&3091093397568475626 &
 6\\
\hline
3 &
 96 &
 17921013728107489666861417152 &
 17921013728107489666861417151 &
 319644167630919465013897831470640254404402368723868992349 &
 17918883386300536523002183680&
 8310947063368032641748342092 &
 6\\
\hline
4 &
 128 &
 10960388158297871697330151881871037028 &
 10960388158297871697330151881871037027 &
 106925141663462215096945420078312037311355711106757002541655645931678791491 &
 10958297067198453652392990431562024960 & 
 3253082388973481812242917579299455335 &
 6\\ 
\hline
5 &
 160 &
 11181085000393941012433719385538976929750386340 &
 11181085000393941012433719385538976929750386339 &
 79684675709633819762973841355295907051437943828599200481216296703376032895835669790667255501 &
 11178266769966960229108283302064411639808000000 &
 4208406996756154635702287087616339813762920102 &
 6\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can also load the `seqsplit` package and that wrap big numbers in `\seqsplit{}` as demonstrated [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13688/121944).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{seqsplit} % added this package
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\caption{Results.}\label{tab1}
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{0.5cm}|}
\hline
N & KS & g & n & C & $\lambda(n)$ & $\mu$ & R\\
\hline
1 &
 32 &
 1572324240 &
 1572324239 &
 \seqsplit{943290716551438163} &
 1572244920 &
 1470930645&6\\
\hline
2 &
 64 &
 \seqsplit{4159540661949250490} &
 \seqsplit{4159540661949250489} &
 \seqsplit{14726610731536157220276939497631624989} &
 \seqsplit{4159171243689855120} & \seqsplit{3091093397568475626} &
 6\\
\hline
3 &
 96 &
 \seqsplit{17921013728107489666861417152} &
 \seqsplit{17921013728107489666861417151} &
 \seqsplit{319644167630919465013897831470640254404402368723868992349} &
 \seqsplit{17918883386300536523002183680} &
 \seqsplit{8310947063368032641748342092} &
 6\\
\hline
4 &
 128 &
 \seqsplit{10960388158297871697330151881871037028} &
 \seqsplit{10960388158297871697330151881871037027} &
 \seqsplit{106925141663462215096945420078312037311355711106757002541655645931678791491} &
 \seqsplit{10958297067198453652392990431562024960} & 
 \seqsplit{3253082388973481812242917579299455335} &
 6\\ 
\hline
5 &
 160 &
 \seqsplit{11181085000393941012433719385538976929750386340} &
 \seqsplit{11181085000393941012433719385538976929750386339} &
 \seqsplit{79684675709633819762973841355295907051437943828599200481216296703376032895835669790667255501} &
 \seqsplit{11178266769966960229108283302064411639808000000} &
 \seqsplit{4208406996756154635702287087616339813762920102} &
 6\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]