# split bibliography pages to avoid overfull box

Tags: biblatex, biber, overfull

I'm trying to print my bibliography, but "pages XXX-XXX" is making overfull boxes. I have already reviewed [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/442308/how-to-adjust-the-line-breaking-in-the-bibliography) but `seqsplit` as mentioned on **ISBNs and other long numbers** is not working, even worse, it throws the next error:

```
!Package etoolbox Error: Toggle 'bbx:pageranges' undefined.
```

This is my file

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[12pt, table, letterpaper]{report}

\usepackage[english,spanish,es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage[
    letterpaper,
    top = 18mm,
    left = 20mm,
    right= 20mm,
    bottom = 18mm
]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[
    thresholdtype=words
]{csquotes}
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=ieee,
    url=false,
    hyperref=true,
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{xurl}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\addbibresource{Bib/References.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{%
%  \mkbibacro{URL}\addcolon\space
    \href{#1}{\nolinkurl{\thefield{urlraw}}}}

\begin{document}
    \pagenumbering{gobble}
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

References.bib

```
@article{palomino-resendiz_design_2018,
    title = {Design and implementation of a robotic active solar distiller based on a Fresnel concentrator and a photovoltaic system},
    volume = {166},
    issn = {0196-8904},
    url = {https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0196890418304175},
    doi = {10.1016/j.enconman.2018.04.069},
    abstract = {},
    pages = {637--647},
    journaltitle = {Energy Conversion and Management},
    shortjournal = {Energy Conversion and Management},
    author = {Palomino-Resendiz, S. I. and Flores-Hernández, D. A. and Lozada-Castillo, N. and Guzmán-Vargas, L. and Luviano-Juárez, A.},
    urldate = {2022-03-18},
    date = {2018-06-15},
    langid = {english},
    keywords = {Desalination, Fresnel lens, Photovoltaic system, Robotic solar distiller, Solar energy},
}

@article{kabeel_performance_2022,
    title = {Performance assessment of the hemispherical solar distillers with the extended cylindrical iron fins: An experimental investigation},
    volume = {61},
    issn = {1110-0168},
    url = {https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1110016822002794},
    doi = {10.1016/j.aej.2022.04.018},
    shorttitle = {Performance assessment of the hemispherical solar distillers with the extended cylindrical iron fins},
    pages = {11149--11157},
    number = {12},
    journaltitle = {Alexandria Engineering Journal},
    shortjournal = {Alexandria Engineering Journal},
    author = {Kabeel, Abd Elnaby and El Hadi Attia, Mohammed and Abdelgaied, Mohamed and Abdullah, A. S. and Bellila, Abdelkader and Abdel-Aziz, Moataz M.},
    urldate = {2022-05-29},
    date = {2022-12-01},
    langid = {english},
    keywords = {Extended cylindrical fins, Hemispherical solar still, Iron fins, Number, Solar energy}
}
```

[image]

I'm compiling my LaTeX code like this

```
xelatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --output-directory=./build --shell-escape %.tex
makeindex -t ./build/%.glg -s ./build/%.ist -o ./build/%.gls ./build/%.glo
makeindex -t ./build/%.alg -s ./build/%.ist -o ./build/%.acr ./build/%.acn
biber --output-directory=./build %
xelatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --output-directory=./build --shell-escape %.tex
```

### Edit

It seems that the problem occurs when adding `csquotes` package. I deleted my file line by line and the problem disappears removing `csquotes` package. But the problem is that I require that package too. Any idea?

Comment: When I compile your MWE I get no overfull boxes (LuaLaTeX: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNj6Z.png, with XeLaTeX some spaces are subtly different, but nothing overflows into the margin either.) How do you compile your document? Did you double check that your MWE reproduces the issue? (Obviously the image shown in the post does not come from the MWE: it has way more citations).

Comment: Alright, with `csquotes` I get https://i.stack.imgur.com/9amrD.png, where one page range definitely runs into the margin. It's not near as bad as shown in your screenshot, but it is visible. Do keep in mind that line breaking is very context sensitive, so any solution that might work (be enough) for a particular case might not be good enough for another case. I can only base my suggestions off the problem I can reproduce.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/442308/35864 has a number of other hints that can help you with line breaking.

Comment: I don't know exactly what code you tried, but the `seqsplit` MWE from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/466691/35864 still works for me. So if you get an error, you need to share the code you tried in an MWE.

Comment: @moewe, maybe `seqsplit` didn't succed cause I need to use `style=ieee` and they use `style=chem-angew`

Comment: And my SS is worse because isn't [1] and [2] but [18] and [20] and that pushes another character to the right. (I think)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line breaking is highly context sensitive, so any solution that might work in a particular situation might not be suitable for another situation, however similar they might be.

Based on the code shown in the question I can reproduce the following overfull box if I add `\usepackage{csquotes}`.

[image: Overfull box: "págs. 637-647," protrudes into the margin (approx "47," is outside the text area).]

In this case of fairly short page numbers I don't think breaking the number itself up randomly is going to give the best results. In a first step I would try to allow line breaking at the hyphen by redefining `\bibrangedash`. By default `spanish.lbx` uses a hyphen at which there cannot be a line break.

This gives us

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{report}
\usepackage[
  letterpaper,
  top = 18mm,
  left = 20mm,
  right= 20mm,
  bottom = 18mm,
]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[english,spanish,es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=ieee,
  url=false,
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\DefineBibliographyExtras{spanish}{%
  \protected\def\bibrangedash{-}%
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{%
%  \mkbibacro{URL}\addcolon\space
    \href{#1}{\nolinkurl{\thefield{urlraw}}}}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{palomino-resendiz_design_2018,
  title        = {Design and implementation of a robotic active solar distiller
                  based on a Fresnel concentrator and a photovoltaic system},
  volume       = {166},
  issn         = {0196-8904},
  url          = {https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0196890418304175},
  doi          = {10.1016/j.enconman.2018.04.069},
  pages        = {637--647},
  journaltitle = {Energy Conversion and Management},
  author       = {Palomino-Resendiz, S. I. and Flores-Hernández, D. A.
                  and Lozada-Castillo, N. and Guzmán-Vargas, L.
                  and Luviano-Juárez, A.},
  urldate      = {2022-03-18},
  date         = {2018-06-15},
  langid       = {english},
}
@article{kabeel_performance_2022,
  title        = {Performance assessment of the hemispherical solar distillers
                  with the extended cylindrical iron fins:
                  An experimental investigation},
  volume       = {61},
  issn         = {1110-0168},
  url          = {https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1110016822002794},
  doi          = {10.1016/j.aej.2022.04.018},
  pages        = {11149--11157},
  number       = {12},
  journaltitle = {Alexandria Engineering Journal},
  author       = {Kabeel, Abd Elnaby and El Hadi Attia, Mohammed
                  and Abdelgaied, Mohamed and Abdullah, A. S. and Bellila, Abdelkader
                  and Abdel-Aziz, Moataz M.},
  urldate      = {2022-05-29},
  date         = {2022-12-01},
  langid       = {english},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  \pagenumbering{gobble}
  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

[image: Same bibliography as above. This time page ranges are broken at "-" resulting in no text protruding into the margin.]

From the looks of it I'm hoping this will also work in the document shown in your screenshot (which is not the MWE).

Personally, I think the `seqsplit` solution is a bit radical (breaking numbers at arbitrary positions can look odd). If the problem persists, I'd probably try one of the generic solutions from [How to adjust the line breaking in the bibliography?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/442308/35864), e.g. `\emergencystretch`.

Comment: Adding both solutions (yours and `\emergencystretch`) solved everything!

Comment: @EduardoJiménez Do keep in mind, though, that the "best" value for `\emergencystrecth` is highly context dependent, so you may have to come back to it from time to time if there are changes to your bibliography layout (however small). The first thing I'd always try is `microtype`, but I think its XeLaTeX support isn't that great (you might get better results with LuaLaTeX there).