# Is it possible to left and right justify a long number that occupies several lines, not including hyphens?

Tags: justification

Example:

17.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002413933445600912769195304792199862634006784029478786788072869945892935572867621333317357495930701726631107846757217774514305738331257370882270432490609514881083995045125041684537114319881662957503685847435886554169475893678885727752704125167002412628528495114066508426812440508332551841981528814369268021319973751020710318778143399862256635312760644968108941033749105453221163285063487929867535316393330419233409594015013089006444349272261007083275038318253286450174581789807668597539323996284962115101591459403395526448027381690581592992365158019894677497416233949919737374940229540654485513584931732037742725960057370239077539709758937378221806826788787253845554904915992600483568620244490508548502164698513522426945403262293561129521092255393248375670000733685077932498730656693016671157639056520530294496529627090443200989651272778526601850401116027806210037822166132759691217110904111252571943669112821921330842766808205185220776304788384943832088532786685922411101029786846742474109961568169188019648607986032108838381855167659740940848444313045421966947460456978184730795817667826491669244501759309401256327957164955725204049174136359866513583854649332936395150607524144913029294695785250731637253509814200162072248727500339013211608038721611226084574681180681651045695562561381348942578054477932160205271759087846624855246834499189892625347680263107999150460309527666966990943127582281424605513943422308588962651184416796963940777586649186736299278809766351898344669254216326495861301398559265247030536356886950231746829224562319089431554727302643976847246759962925198620530016986363127254537350240095283782213763219582770444109636777052639754487940950653755620668436931846369999771743305879646021611717530580076842049042435585761478245344700395802547945932225208877961305501194989307197286399157464320636139110114183572581278098204193453437598445585573805418787689750133613224568174507608609400029938767623255424145456105196787452615839841786011082672914021206501114142602783544440839322700666558281000324292188357529736970218348326619618455393303735961774756425761981819133892530563997073989533736231795182036939100741531889600336999464580051273840634739337541567462085585101653429486822880097131086961941762430594400938504027745604537104875885136225859165780307972003895765889006323807239315414405233544263392712227212628118697364811340835695253261175033886415797646812167441580345296143928127876413700356105966903438991411574338179609598136220691698954874288442490349990057665228881743211809808088585597445453532447164734628885908935475143018763542042071185720058282528204379378816544622704114909886569157803017627017986660219601129696081481393184312121449536200056388494078450834378626806379187803033765272048411615951008943373505974494429197171873783341145078823252935661997369631850154822559155314132078035276550024682800437100903288107875664804862307456292906483696533290944505517074322641030557696748348955074233326718343290419144291600761758531500929008014042903726593406628761646116145826691985335093381430696388746321356874093603117475067501031424438741530636614493627421906406937522471749937786982483800123216187352175628673233416266599255542902786787089816529765719113542036540493672108477772925270561924680531095372331043900981314326387427674932672752430329081000371570480734788802180855719124169210941683778616551902288741661342003486754260787250743710939170542838611522060843230448731745246370461406539279057622844818752718376548001504112283792962923384399106886150503800258759018643220430516546666624743424368281324092080971954301926630523619230113792377719841695525271009574679036958277549098755158968968115882079994222176405621279208252820615673585324890317378899495428229626767955384248042847692238607102944540242305610910479928695486360873947312096251580544506920406090370733964476510268954255071205675294832429146047074979961633278782406490844177735777302554480955408723691824469715320341647182780724643213356505922317233830198888185190704070477113764887688149708707701683054553288363946108125860633782570285975359628563807457688555287274851135113442522023922234060081632837295600087844627141437812173692559214280228439776828625209917905314377658371103291028853042861067800949482320107843949334413853186978913865661352912713219942871033748639351711062530435957855255523125961499245794437346465219503024686394709461551615924676705581581753190758224063582621780148296628973946096625097877528054128630924444683187837336072843346661459460490907482575782171360371186343142015464398699090268266226233227046066254015425561006737441712908933999225751892544000610288269379785313218359579811947736237682968084220145719861025558914373375316772695878426093407609207394900188169638637646511318686369686719588930482388764681967898928481532039795390236361157626591962151736920818739209243625559460080414141725569203056005134473554291843576371834363432834935891909930995231661226125637663124074251145538629527639814006206948013051077216871847354549648360183568577371156023249305361373367468049065230732523144685593765609679853934498160750409780278767934726140421453303844208418595559882565677999213288722868841215780338296993652466767166510418339847364767095794907094645283357830354794673177829353722057614753508839881348466707549901927021073918493731236291191490746635197068605736336397986749848344957410829624511718198246135999846163156726000600119367690935618824488052512860513178960828624309693341377924274453814317966580840355358635311695334929660302774824329986742069813602315051823129183460122330790129422596739719395429780289160391155613304202649986414325395174791967725087760178205969919058488944790729237055405887043382861250394982829946736965587739700527656585836918592510036388097307318595541353823918154376326362946725754404333536916502051223625126272758624962388680284158056780224041994629833396305080718277223358183099116382532588078583862733272758127195306975250004559010133271193444695093297154477453174182421592140523318939424046521098415123214892157162834919867033152834093553233336492383964996716237440277442199635728075030810294700572322913584693758384272636432648585798446206061224428744492499823572280252903944532694938066863473092335857237812727383819995765574335372415149609401615589214698072769751298673163457548215588611260862266667400007693611244508495504056797533499303112425527803566959261802867435457970493699519491509872900367562641651054038083061341496552610376706132264390594431607613229166067795058595363222668510445455042663680493336173192745483373219930552094456364270038386653632880679401304324258756992454652006252482768916988320382941884406810257802524895571408613435862714771541947428957442780083897478779244352407228066295979497608259890499475047846711028911752112684746120288654037750865370271227502360392822042626544127306545739767362318201157803176688461584613002854434135230355135220216147488176614958436365286684416031993224843546119361644429390349365661086682507645099673723561324883952771616710286154230159450288587968973735087932472165403234555272744433082158840834181261182472492756649045047833997161291446497207558375827455749336401833643852958155170712619042005505793719437034661734430184623450608397795809752795617881159322704299950125151072653580042660412967064099831667216623574937118126652172526725054326633282195454108148217240241748881082206097388212872446804029245009703354299232197363281372553073660041950968674898196607938368378119301457860682316086629794319592893633534940751995254081234375531275919441041828853213995252965598040093067023978537739175482443174890296406922673002207855674173578937948464623275367181060088569310011918123255524386564108048983955166646480260424041738787304906407343064023045108565578280272413869102727076233089931744927241006981051111085294831215978829816777411121953942906508145057520426833644176181858019405248777418589503942025898345524049689643818386317406322713947716288862440365791108127563544457840470005026553145645885452116226219691734152370247412332548602970909983294817644018216355375534599214035609400436908667051762418702620669783400381209222213951039105364290407983779121714225428405674556226157820422752186937377625755939310483376184160313733659167671519535646110968167874148118534691409736673166558717057605366213320813173230337060522708952220921627317050682644794720176955326179904400497641420335169483807566359058946401915854871970914208072927559387913439947246423943840424437193256759225653492075563408991300303880287115056302666845107641200865057088631047321391329326333431020720624962826726433514940959536529309341470718046554695300715405743842112737370813204288310044341078467783443959814978569706584589398196228574172573513662946325808744490573519515049676939628509400283626264715719417293509252077206309893956549571345412499495196343514091392787647198231425236434821364182937114482419953606997678209847999857563729043944059633941897151066394176626579531016199526542103731768082611053898533521421817020881750451584975984875467471099513932548707696849610851295016335722863869543465201371259089636813734100159108545864511210563530907246868530000479405721496762900240203443962286772915485840083495291821616605089985736580297550130361533610577910502096330294736468176003535329460211865956983126135959319127548430930861144991065667454369620503419318891469439691975869966214593981387402777824338938049608396471183800858165725385812907445018505818329365766937301304583878146026084715236867462111545896366640312180756600226629316912366374772001186207417170052971806993163877904993306251275906272030677060684726259447622157173573316734794264731854722452711420639337313382909024350273451628202468733288850526221706668526292996129306...

Comment: do you really want it justified ie adding space between digits to reach the right margin, or just allow line breaking (as in your example above)

Comment: Thank you, David. I want just allow line breaking (as in my example above).

Comment: see seqsplit https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=seqsplit

Comment: Potential duplicate: [Splitting very big numbers over several lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13688)

Comment: Yes, David. I have solved the problem with seqsplit. Thanks!. Best regards!.