# How to typeset large numbers

Tags: numbering, formatting

I need to typeset some very large numbers that span a number of lines, is there a way in LaTeX to do this?

Comment: Do you need the subsequent lines to wrap around the numbers?

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6171/wrapping-long-lines-that-contain-no-spaces help?

Comment: @Emre yes they have to wrap.

Comment: @mathpasha I am not sure, if you are looking to typeset, big integers or large sized numbers as in font-size. Can you please clarify?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

For typesetting large integers  you can use the package `numprint`.

You will need to  set the thousands separator to your liking (I have used a space).

Here, is a minimal that can do this. The number  was generated using Heiko Oberdiek's `bigintcalc`. The sample number is the 1279 [Mersenne](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime) number calculated with the macro `\Mersenne`, shown in the minimal below. As this is calculated using a power function it takes about 15 seconds to process!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{numprint}
\usepackage{bigintcalc}
\begin{document}
 \npthousandsep{ }
\def\Mersenne#1{%
  \begingroup
  \par\noindent\parindent=0pt
  $M_{#1}=$\par
  \def\exponent##1{\bigintcalcPow{2}{##1}}%
  \numprint{\bigintcalcSub{\exponent{#1}}{1}}
  \endgroup
}

\Mersenne{1279}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: To use thin spaces as separators, `\npthousandsep{\ensuremath\,\allowbreak}` would work. Better in my opinion than full spaces.

Answer (score 15):

That depends on what you are trying to achieve; one possibility would be to explicitly select the font size (using Computer Modern fonts this requires the `fix-cm` package):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fix-cm}

\begin{document}

{\fontsize{40}{48}\selectfont 2}

{\fontsize{90}{108}\selectfont 2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Only two other people like your joke? What a pity! It is beautiful.

Answer (score 14):

`numprint` seems to fail on *very* large numbers, e.g. the number 2011^2011 requested in [How to typeset long numbers in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88818/15925).  One possibility in such cases is to use `siunitx` and its group separator option as follows (number computed in computer algebra package):

[image: Start]

...2 pages later...

[image: End]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\num[group-separator={\ifmmode\egroup\egroup\)\egroup\ \bgroup\(\bgroup\bgroup\fi}]{14510219094756835443971804257188873072794015545666081939388855749525896884654481242616934781472275243051888663874155206933903154198120231191628992301817135048200098980176752739362987878664059532850107984545109970319612751146817229127042379603090727086757619024725981449720739503384463675281844597701405345770843465000975070415089613332211172182623690270574999349969317078016313807025422481160546843537968347603649315792489605777834323805460413034900278406748673158431279064662352847958818691708253398792960152785338035354737318651122455328213785355488400398210887854142389370989758234640130506260675874047790025842440885467711037139174297690267704869910896371907830244052230101607377315283106967320104784230128581678356733651972721303261927010476541549034821238262101145454460744235581503300804731781313297449779427755185487515045090431608215979542642856019280583688925217816428602650546812760023727355869719417344689058172044429829389003403686273002229187524537247634918086547752450203224546712251149064592155973342626090620714944165674055016953473475341294887308595629097007472410431532121906108088957572282026310714783107497418246512593517465039367233934654168224981093602413155513695182786967364980581565478119065103575984826265255862323181676653416967689802233214088349730947331994599695181920268130161299405995782565629800468000440941288170069450580804552732721486676013741611681944793619673798886562111764156394552401369401761640290957237757115523776564496524398167632743424880002194878959906134022876584000151040026186364933922729445416063033887021748096756407502273874073139311897811267095400718994554595717706599595291309840369068932559458206582023161200627335416474012488815016172330337260587349246890637716151044386991611573955523916598749709975716622679748797842147158726687759796825231375555889423050904597779670669542392325007347450602190569159391485653708628977505864044630073984857552417164766694174007446237442294526801441688015836679834960908965063795498787911525043365680105157251534733012502707949586129922040981734237315570322398309605732325741869439738326210465859465676096641936226281199767693354773928874388433433619697484325389804752325569617438122436340776811759892840966332713004452194028293166786594323316988588540548337522771148090464530294831596457585835024566018309518347915085787882246767059251983592015486463678669596438592049008314992556342253597099170817261519193110958315582579579612590897973375077675322925722167305656337802318288366746967854216485913798801485378624760127419739516066805063615298186443155714847814227168397129307200659528151215347298459700123443326572253651823725673379629800162640998646395994184482388600983767597362373264516098864159026279963726949742425428965389974474206288539025523008779505101179403183530399923607128711649749417952856834146668247431995446772474542494576842294761706230522253316484353430938708094756603913651373251537309372016056269711748597099537816245334412718722673658907648750157979936216611490736992538374477600849705624013181091770128676485069581054048874685904083050140375491505461484946125125451337979611764072862286605372712106006826370411836898330301429634452349794501412248777505760614344490849783569014504371505461770328495059377607202264878613571439464276520675474725198021564621051600119505652211213532992622202360790091815754312912492831778390646659560040690459901136056449162132579354760291911193820625422431352244142409372672255981998554730721402236896068017291399002608524659494733156458560468454286972744117043980326910174676178911707063103605254915304021061697977849611533820629613317114846889476696181908015744691773684581421721766116278136401642504413267688296553061773640889487079941079523319237250497373798734700149432993920460571528295808178065313882435208470362653529114065796062572729665041898351559680918279839147245393054880997783582680218593925594607624500090379662522764884879472497228739168678792217895918597323042889902923183460534005812014216501363645976671584231574633653237845999560572585757923903205441980717507754148387516844031980736798705250383427695858961777809551804058339251044381692967273519833836087499347445601294743806210482771755946615364138025776699592214328553465384862908829172871443071701627260637948355406567656586196261571857797351973872753455115341974403208689931822888840618095837856835836394220964167373693182043337821269170972524622932791811888912799516823430014684735838761857776779589974226842805074532243035588934778154324933509023535093506616335938383230021260887567310329094908408756605538385397234006271831785200944648397254513110833878153213909414855156147406580199544926314022129562346840811295917348374741554351275966099497539583772438559776254413455134392518272577650575336568062777244668565133254732650588948151145265262483174452321786600631078667589115400895685481443896662624596421972072634179998128521551328524409147039181155195254079054125314833707693253478332206243285173108787414261108600363476728627922180452603493453425271127307705393556306352032635208921648129782670552618600278257768436977627400984290219034868885655233425867631329453946124234192945444292062390064139287501070023602474691217791123210303476034915878041468974260381740828122980062146438949536001669362613825058563639940617077400121977921846377164005316723309241731235427352206528561532205796843631685579889554180615071319939092634080756482668988152398561724049845236882408823368740724293855662938714848076386745237708153888259668172851739419865414324087115957051254617425968124768603533017735321784079001850457325218829987911483131047432710646357341089726726268908301963807638384000153712817560155006091798147666549321736102030430275572850304627126716322739932121477170815946271923065311867369532267887377248219996879400509573450413921221205456088819521230510667781563476106206963190199926903895644156241024327814735639665740125951619966598339326080242254271213340903963049744522583041693089877597632573932526178555920706300304747852396865431378278487499260694027311870364355410328667112749998467439373896003064860381390956802707851152642580551808484506908569732595512165106587801736771619118518777303548767371525823564478594570943150422943471819366503424051758233597273684831997197296226005537112653183943361132860240388669248557201867337362480675098941420786903330080052975972994678444503888277589320711001095589217883075728263558182980761933023136478190685967473848614410589586742282218929572405880168032768662254225628649076169101399729794796356267028950517111994339221184328582454650116709719362617008710352054818584996741050395663202561403165353399920824824813672014368423783327933853524295735698077629063531327012611}

\end{document}
```

Comment: how to I make it  group by 4 digits?

Comment: @MaoYiyi `siunitx` only does groups of 3, because it is designed to follow the SI standards. If your number is from an external application then I would use an external tool to group the digits appropriately.  Otherwise I suggest you ask a separate question on this site.

Comment: Remark, this implementation is understandably fragile because it relies on the exact number of grouping layers created by `siunitx` package. In newer versions it's broken, refer to [errors - How to show extremely large number in overleaf? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/680758/how-to-show-extremely-large-number-in-overleaf).