# How do I expand this number into full decimal (non-scientific) notation?

Tags: equations

I need to typeset the result of 88.6 to the 53rd power multiplied by 9216.

What I need is the full number, as part of a 6 page long equation of how long it would take to walk to the Andromeda Galaxy at 4 Mph. It should not be in scientific notation.

Comment: That number has over 100 digits. Are you suggestion it should fit on a single line of text?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a question about TeX, LaTeX or its friends. Perhaps math.stackexchange.com might be a better place to ask it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).  I don't how else this is TeX related but to suggest `$88.6^{53} \times 9216 = 1.508 \times 10^{107}$`

Comment: Yes, I need it to because it is part of a 6 page long equation of how long it would take to walk to the Andromeda Galaxy at 4 Mph. It can not be in scientific notation.

Comment: Oh, I thought this would be the right place to ask this question. Sorry for wasting anybody's time.

Comment: @CameronJames Sometimes it is:)

Comment: @CameronJames Me thinks you should modify the title to reflect the question better.

Answer (score 12):

Unfortunately, `bigintcalc` allows computations only with integers. But in this case you *know* the number of digits in the integer part: the base 10 logarithm of `88.6^53 * 9216` is, approximately 107.178 and so we can perform the operation in integer arithmetic and adjust the result to have 108 digits in the integer part:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,l3str,bigintcalc}
\usepackage{numprint}

\npthousandsep{\hspace{.33333em plus .16667em minus .11111em}}
\npdecimalsign{.}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\xnumprint}{mm}
 { % #1 = bigint expression, #2 = decimal places
  \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
  \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpb_tl { \str_substr:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { #2 } { } }
  \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \str_substr:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { } { #2 } }
  \use:x { \exp_not:N \numprint { \l_tmpa_tl.\l_tmpb_tl } }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\noindent\xnumprint{\bigintcalcMul{\bigintcalcPow{886}{53}}{9216}}{108}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm confused why there are 2 answers to this problem that are very different numbers so I typed in the code:          Z = IntegerRing()
a = str(Z(886^53*9216))                                     into [here](http://www.sagemath.org/eval.html) [note that there are 2 lines-the second line starts with a=] and got egreg's answer. Can the other answer be correct? If not, why has it gotten so many points?

Comment: @DJP Yiannis's answer uses a wrong figure: `86^53`. I checked with `bc -l` and the integral part is correct (I guess also the decimal part).

Comment: Thanks! I didn't notice the '8' was missing...

Comment: @DJP Oops! Didn't notice I typed the wrong digit either. Did it very quickly on the way to work in the morning. I guess it got upvoted as the question was standing on -4votes and closed and most people thought it couldn't be done using TeX. Here we try to upvote to encourage answers and reward effort. Personally I voted egreg's answer as well for his effort to get the decimal part right.

Comment: That reminds me: +1 for both, and also the question.

Answer (score 8):

Here is how:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bigintcalc}
\begin{document}
\bigintcalcMul{\bigintcalcPow{86}{53}}{9216}
\end{document}
```

To format it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{numprint}
\npthousandsep{ }
\usepackage{bigintcalc}
\begin{document}
\numprint{\bigintcalcMul{\bigintcalcPow{86}{53}}{9216}}
\end{document}
```

(Just a small error on the decimal).

[image]

You may also find this [How to typeset large numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15911/how-to-typeset-large-numbers), useful.

You might also like to place it in a parbox and add a phantom character to line up the thousands,

[image]