# How to typeset long numbers in LaTeX

Tags: line-breaking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to typeset large numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15911/how-to-typeset-large-numbers)

I saw the posts on how to typeset long *formulas* into LaTeX, but I just want to output a really long number into LaTeX.

`2011^2011` is long, and I want to demonstrate that its last 3 digits are actually 611.

However, it outputs onto one line and doesn't fit.

So: How do I force it to break?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Does this question help you? [How to typeset large numbers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15911/how-to-typeset-large-numbers) If so, please tell us, or point out why it doesn't.

Comment: φ(100) = 40; 2011 ≡ 11 (mod 1000), 2011 ≡ 11 (mod 40); thus 2011^2011 ≡ 11^2011 ≡ 11^11 (mod 1000) and 11^11 = 285311670611. Yes, the last three digits are 611. :)

Comment: It would be much easier to format your number in your favorite editor such that each line has say 60 digits and then paste it into a TeX file. Big numbers and TeX don't get along well so leave the typesetting to TeX but handle the delicate math to something else.

Comment: The question http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15911/15925 egreg points to looks like a duplicate.  However, the `numprint` solution there failed on your example, so I have posted a second solution to that question there that copes with your case.