# Typeset a number with many digits in the align environment

Tags: math-mode, equations, typography, siunitx

Questions like this have been asked before, [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15911/how-to-typeset-large-numbers) [and here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88818/how-to-typeset-long-numbers-in-latex), but neither of these are within a math enviroment.

In context, I would like to type set the approximate solution to an integral to 100 digits.

```
\begin{align*}
I &=  \left[\left[\cos(1) + \operatorname{Si}(1)\right] - \left[-\left(\operatorname{Si}(0)-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right]\right] \\
I &=  \cos(1) + \operatorname{Si}(1) -\frac{\pi}{2} \\
I &\approxeq\num{-0.08441095055957388688903177037359518055393632433151889234592026720612077182783481670736342350213473343}
\end{align*}
```

For an minimal example, try to typeset

```
\begin{align}
\pi \approxeq 3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208998628034825342117067982148086513282306647093844609550582231725359408128481117450284102701938521105559644622948954930381964428810975665933446128475648233786783165271201909145648566923460348610454326648213393607260249141273724587006606315588174881520920962829254091715364367892590360011330530548820466521384146951941511609433057270365759591953092186117381932611793105118548074462379962749567351885752724891227938183011949129833673362440656643086021394946395224737190702179860943702770539217176293176752384674818467669405132000568127145263560827785771342757789609173637178721468440901224953430146549585371050792279689258923542019956112129021960864034418159813629774771309960518707211349999998372978049951059731732816096318595024459455346908302642522308253344685035261931188171010003137838752886587533208381420617177669147303598253490428755468731159562863882353787593751957781857780532171226806613001927876611195909216420198938095257201065485863278865936153381827968230301952035301852968995773622599413891249721775283479131515574857242454150695950829533116861727855889075098381754637464939319255060400927701671139009848824012858361603563707660104710181942955596198946767837449448255379774726847104047534646208046684259069491293313677028989152104752162056966024058038150193511253382430035587640247496473263914199272604269922796782354781636009341721641219924586315030286182974555706749838505494588586926995690927210797509302955321165344987202755960236480665499119881834797753566369807426542527862551818417574672890977772793800081647060016145249192173217214772350141441973568548161361157352552133475741849468438523323907394143334547762416862518983569485562099219222184272550254256887671790494601653466804988627232791786085784383827967976681454100953883786360950680064225125205117392984896084128488626945604241965285022210661186306744278622039194945047123713786960956364371917287467764657573962413890865832645995813390478027590099465764078951269468398352
\end{align}
```

It appears that `\num` from `siunitx` doesn't work, nor does `numprint`.

Does anyone have a solution?

## Final Awnser

The final macro that I went with is:

```
\newcommand{\longnum}[1]{%
    \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-5em\relax}{\num[group-separator={\egroup\egroup\)\egroup\,\linebreak[0]\bgroup\(\iffalse\)\fi\bgroup\bgroup}]{#1}\dots}%
}
```

This will only work for 8.5in width paper and equations of the form  `X =` .
To make it work for other places, change the `-5em`.
Using `linegoal` did not work for me, as it made the equation not fit the margins.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the [`siunitx` solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88922/16595) from [How to typeset large numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15911/16595) and the `linegoal` solution from my [half-baked solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/100499/16595) to [Compute remaining horizontal space in align environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/100495/16595) we can get the following.

You can un-outcomment the `\ifmeasuring@\else` and `\fi` segments to see a version where the math content is somewhat centered, the number though goes until the right edge of the text.

Also, this does not account for an equation number, especially *with* `\ifmeasuring@`, the equation number will be typeset way in the margin.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,siunitx,amssymb,linegoal}
\usepackage[showframe,pass]{geometry}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\longnum[2][]{%
%  \ifmeasuring@\else
  \parbox[t]{\linegoal}{\num[group-separator={\egroup\egroup\)\egroup\,\linebreak[0]\bgroup\(\bgroup\bgroup},#1]{#2}}%
%  \fi
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
I &=  \left[\left[\cos(1) + \operatorname{Si}(1)\right] - \left[-\left(\operatorname{Si}(0)-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right]\right] \\
I &=  \cos(1) + \operatorname{Si}(1) -\frac{\pi}{2} \\
I & \approxeq\longnum{-0.08441095055957388688903177037359518055393632433151889234592026720612077182783481670736342350213473343}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Hmm, it seems to mess up syntax highlighting. Everything after it is recognised as an equation.
Anyway, while this works, it does look fairly awkward. How could we account for a tag, and indent the second line so that it lines up with the first?

Comment: @NictraSavios The highlighting is an editor issue (I have it, too). For the tag, we could subtract its with from `\linegoal`, say `\dimexpr-1.5em+\linegoal\relax`. Regarding the second line: Do it manually or use `\raggedleft`.

Comment: Alright, now would there be a way to fix the editor issue? It's a bit nitpicky, but if it was possible, this would be an ideal solution.

Comment: @NictraSavios - Which editor do you use?

Comment: @NictraSavios You can try adding `\)` after the `%`, some editors seem to accept this (some sources suggest this). If this fails, you can add `\iffalse\)\fi` either directly after the offending `\(` or after the whole `\parbox` or after `}` from the definition of `\longnum`.

Comment: Maybe `.75\linegoal` could be better not to push the alignment to the margin, while giving room for several digits.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I can't seem to make it line up to the end margin, like other equations. http://oi40.tinypic.com/2v26t0p.jpg

Using: `\newcommand*\longnum[2][]{%
  \parbox[t]{\dimexpr-1.5em+0.9\linegoal}{\num[group-separator={\egroup\egroup\)\egroup\,\linebreak[0]\bgroup\(\iffalse\)\fi\bgroup\bgroup},#1]{#2}}%
}`

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Using a box length of `\dimexpr+\linewidth-5em\relax` seems to work better than `\dimexpr-1.5em+\linegoal\relax`. It avoids the above issue. Is there a reason to use `linegoal`?