# How can I make this large number fit into my latex document?

Tags: spacing, formatting, code, setspace

I've tried using different codes to fit this large number, but it runs off the page. It does not fit. I am fairly new to LaTex, so your help would be very helful.

Below is the number and what I've tried but has not worked.

```
\hspace{-4.5cm}$114381625757888867669235779976146612010218296721
204236256256184293576935245733897830597123563958705058989075147599290026879543541$
$= 3490529510847650949147849619903898133417764638493387843990820577
\times
3276913299326670954996198819083446141317764296
7992942539798288533$
```

Comment: Numbers aren't generally broken over lines (you couldn't use a hyphen, it's too similar to a minus) but I'm sure we've discussed this before. Found it.

Comment: How is supposed  that long numbers must  be "fitted" ?  Reducing the font size?  Breaking the number in several lines ? Streching the numbers? There are not acceptable solution, EMHO, except use scientific notation.

Answer (score 0):

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15914/75284 adapted to your situation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{numprint}
\begin{document}
\npthousandsep{\ensuremath\,\allowbreak}
\begingroup
\par\noindent\parindent=0pt
\numprint{114381625757888867669235779976146612010218296721
204236256256184293576935245733897830597123563958705058989075147599290026879543541}

\(=\) \numprint{3490529510847650949147849619903898133417764638493387843990820577}

\(\times\)

\numprint{3276913299326670954996198819083446141317764296
7992942539798288533}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

The `\npthousandsep{\ensuremath\,\allowbreak}` is there to have thin spaces as thousand group separators.