# Wrap a long word or number in a beamer slide

Tags: beamer

I would like to have a slide using Beamer that is almost filled with the digits of a very large number, e.g. 1233213283216137678612738....   (5000 digits).

I use the following:

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Big number}
1233213283216137678612738567566578578587567567858675875....
\end{frame}
```

but the result is just one line with digits going out of the margins. Is there a way to set the margins of the slide such that the digits continue to the next line when reaching the margin?

Comment: Try the suggestion posted here: [How to typeset large numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88922/5764)