# How to show extremely large number in overleaf?

Tags: errors, formatting

I need to show the following Private exponent in overleaf:

```
25895107538405649688030348996832713569445142790008475239637397869318784772667910655793716697799988593837576806840542707041271719702620953276919316028023188172858715581748693955423981219211598229098207640461515095150909429377751547299151096360584320956677376726662632688048877225179958200801974706011616367315862498611926410040512147744526352916435462209101103537694846510922824847023862008422155278088141453891428873975315666229324633723121265174758771509620329121402787550477990418192871933144340836905002232237390458813578151790533395549611841467387066143850419849217555661401483288249447617461025564522092185741861
```

I tried to implement solution from [this link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88922/293652).
But it is giving me many errors such as:

```
Extra }, or forgotten $.
<argument> $25\ifmmode \egroup 
                               \egroup \)\egroup \ \bgroup \(\bgroup \bgroup...
l.6 ...401483288249447617461025564522092185741861}
                                                  
I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.



<inserted text> 
                }
l.6 ...401483288249447617461025564522092185741861}
                                                  
I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.
...
```

Could you please help me work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The example fails with newer versions of `siunitx`. But you can use, e.g., `\linebreak[1]` to allow line breaks instead of temporary end the math mode:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\num[group-separator={\ \linebreak[1]}]{14510219094756835443971804257188873072794015545666081939388855749525896884654481242616934781472275243051888663874155206933903154198120231191628992301817135048200098980176752739362987878664059532850107984545109970319612751146817229127042379603090727086757619024725981449720739503384463675281844597701405345770843465000975070415089613332211172182623690270574999349969317078016313807025422481160546843537968347603649315792489605777834323805460413034900278406748673158431279064662352847958818691708253398792960152785338035354737318651122455328213785355488400398210887854142389370989758234640130506260675874047790025842440885467711037139174297690267704869910896371907830244052230101607377315283106967320104784230128581678356733651972721303261927010476541549034821238262101145454460744235581503300804731781313297449779427755185487515045090431608215979542642856019280583688925217816428602650546812760023727355869719417344689058172044429829389003403686273002229187524537247634918086547752450203224546712251149064592155973342626090620714944165674055016953473475341294887308595629097007472410431532121906108088957572282026310714783107497418246512593517465039367233934654168224981093602413155513695182786967364980581565478119065103575984826265255862323181676653416967689802233214088349730947331994599695181920268130161299405995782565629800468000440941288170069450580804552732721486676013741611681944793619673798886562111764156394552401369401761640290957237757115523776564496524398167632743424880002194878959906134022876584000151040026186364933922729445416063033887021748096756407502273874073139311897811267095400718994554595717706599595291309840369068932559458206582023161200627335416474012488815016172330337260587349246890637716151044386991611573955523916598749709975716622679748797842147158726687759796825231375555889423050904597779670669542392325007347450602190569159391485653708628977505864044630073984857552417164766694174007446237442294526801441688015836679834960908965063795498787911525043365680105157251534733012502707949586129922040981734237315570322398309605732325741869439738326210465859465676096641936226281199767693354773928874388433433619697484325389804752325569617438122436340776811759892840966332713004452194028293166786594323316988588540548337522771148090464530294831596457585835024566018309518347915085787882246767059251983592015486463678669596438592049008314992556342253597099170817261519193110958315582579579612590897973375077675322925722167305656337802318288366746967854216485913798801485378624760127419739516066805063615298186443155714847814227168397129307200659528151215347298459700123443326572253651823725673379629800162640998646395994184482388600983767597362373264516098864159026279963726949742425428965389974474206288539025523008779505101179403183530399923607128711649749417952856834146668247431995446772474542494576842294761706230522253316484353430938708094756603913651373251537309372016056269711748597099537816245334412718722673658907648750157979936216611490736992538374477600849705624013181091770128676485069581054048874685904083050140375491505461484946125125451337979611764072862286605372712106006826370411836898330301429634452349794501412248777505760614344490849783569014504371505461770328495059377607202264878613571439464276520675474725198021564621051600119505652211213532992622202360790091815754312912492831778390646659560040690459901136056449162132579354760291911193820625422431352244142409372672255981998554730721402236896068017291399002608524659494733156458560468454286972744117043980326910174676178911707063103605254915304021061697977849611533820629613317114846889476696181908015744691773684581421721766116278136401642504413267688296553061773640889487079941079523319237250497373798734700149432993920460571528295808178065313882435208470362653529114065796062572729665041898351559680918279839147245393054880997783582680218593925594607624500090379662522764884879472497228739168678792217895918597323042889902923183460534005812014216501363645976671584231574633653237845999560572585757923903205441980717507754148387516844031980736798705250383427695858961777809551804058339251044381692967273519833836087499347445601294743806210482771755946615364138025776699592214328553465384862908829172871443071701627260637948355406567656586196261571857797351973872753455115341974403208689931822888840618095837856835836394220964167373693182043337821269170972524622932791811888912799516823430014684735838761857776779589974226842805074532243035588934778154324933509023535093506616335938383230021260887567310329094908408756605538385397234006271831785200944648397254513110833878153213909414855156147406580199544926314022129562346840811295917348374741554351275966099497539583772438559776254413455134392518272577650575336568062777244668565133254732650588948151145265262483174452321786600631078667589115400895685481443896662624596421972072634179998128521551328524409147039181155195254079054125314833707693253478332206243285173108787414261108600363476728627922180452603493453425271127307705393556306352032635208921648129782670552618600278257768436977627400984290219034868885655233425867631329453946124234192945444292062390064139287501070023602474691217791123210303476034915878041468974260381740828122980062146438949536001669362613825058563639940617077400121977921846377164005316723309241731235427352206528561532205796843631685579889554180615071319939092634080756482668988152398561724049845236882408823368740724293855662938714848076386745237708153888259668172851739419865414324087115957051254617425968124768603533017735321784079001850457325218829987911483131047432710646357341089726726268908301963807638384000153712817560155006091798147666549321736102030430275572850304627126716322739932121477170815946271923065311867369532267887377248219996879400509573450413921221205456088819521230510667781563476106206963190199926903895644156241024327814735639665740125951619966598339326080242254271213340903963049744522583041693089877597632573932526178555920706300304747852396865431378278487499260694027311870364355410328667112749998467439373896003064860381390956802707851152642580551808484506908569732595512165106587801736771619118518777303548767371525823564478594570943150422943471819366503424051758233597273684831997197296226005537112653183943361132860240388669248557201867337362480675098941420786903330080052975972994678444503888277589320711001095589217883075728263558182980761933023136478190685967473848614410589586742282218929572405880168032768662254225628649076169101399729794796356267028950517111994339221184328582454650116709719362617008710352054818584996741050395663202561403165353399920824824813672014368423783327933853524295735698077629063531327012611}

\end{document}
```

[image: three pages with one number]

Comment: It worked. I hope it will help others too.