# How to break a long URL

Tags: hyperref, line-breaking, urls

I have a long URL. I use the package `breakurl`, and it works fine outside of an `enumerate` environment, but not when it is on an `\item`.

```
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{breakurl}
\begin{enumerate}
\item svn co \burl{https://svn.xxx.ch/reps/yyyyyyyyyy/Publications/ABC-paper-2012/trunk ABC-paper-2012}
\end{enumerate}
```

How can I give the URL a line break?

**Edit:** If I remove `margin=3cm`, it works properly. It seems to be an interaction between `geometry` and `breakurl`.

Comment: The problem with all the answers, I think, provided to this question is that (when a certain URL is broken across multiple lines) every PDF viewer which I tried will **only highlight that line** of the URL which one is clicking on (and **not the complete** URL), which is confusing. Anybody knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

**Update Jan 2022**: Back when I originally wrote this answer, the [xurl](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xurl) package -- so named, presumably, because it greatly e**x**tends the capabilities of the [url](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/url) package -- hadn't been written yet. However, it exists now, and that's why I would no longer recommend the answer shown below, i.e., running

```
\usepackage[hyphenbreaks]{breakurl}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
```

Instead, I would just run

```
\usepackage{xurl}
```

Quoting from the introductory section of the user guide of the `xurl` package:

> Package xurl loads package url by default and defines possible [line breaks in URLs] for all alphanumerical
> characters and `=` `/` `.` `:` `*` `-` `~` `'` `"`
>
> All arguments which are valid for [the] `url` [package] can be used. It will be passed to package url. xurl itself has
> no special optional argument. For more information read the documentation of package url.

Note that it is *not* necessary to specify the package option `hyphens` to allow line breaks to occur at the `-` (hyphen) character. If you want to allow line breaks to occur at *spaces* in a URL string, while *not* suppressing spaces elsewhere in the URL string, be sure to load `xurl` with the options `spaces` and `obeyspaces`.

---

It should be noted up front that the long-URL issues you are encountering can arise *regardless* of whether the URL occurs inside an `enumerate` environment or not.

By default, if a URL string contains a hyphen character, neither `\burl` of the `breakurl` package nor `\url` of the `url` package will insert a linebreak after a hyphen character. (This setting is chosen to avoid ambiguities over whether the hyphen character is a part of the URL string or not.) To override the default setting, load the `breakurl` package with the `hyphenbreaks` option or, equivalently, load the `url` package with the `hyphens` option set (and use the command `\url` instead of `\burl`, of course).

However, even with the `hyphenbreaks`/`hyphens` options set, overfull lines can still occur. An additional measure you may have to take is to issue the command `\sloppy`. This directive lets TeX expand the amount of interword whitespace (almost) arbitrarily to support its efforts to avoid overfull lines.

The following, modified form of your MWE shows how this works. The packages `breakurl` and `url` are loaded with the options `hyphenbreaks` and `hyphens`, respectively. Even so, the first two items in the enumeration, which use the `\burl` and `\url` commands, produce overfull lines. In contrast, the third and fourth items, for which the directive `\sloppy` is in effect, do not produce overfull lines. (By the way, in this MWE the scope of the `\sloppy` directive ends at the `\end{enumerate}` statement.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % load paragraphs of filler text
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[hyphenbreaks]{breakurl}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[2] % generate some filler text (to show width of text block)

\begin{enumerate}
\item
svn co \burl{https://svn.xxx.ch/reps/yyyyyyyyyy/Publications/ABC-paper-2012/trunk ABC-paper-2012}
\item 
svn co \url{https://svn.xxx.ch/reps/yyyyyyyyyy/Publications/ABC-paper-2012/trunk ABC-paper-2012}
\item
\sloppy
svn co \burl{https://svn.xxx.ch/reps/yyyyyyyyyy/Publications/ABC-paper-2012/trunk ABC-paper-2012}
\item 
svn co \url{https://svn.xxx.ch/reps/yyyyyyyyyy/Publications/ABC-paper-2012/trunk ABC-paper-2012}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Barth You can use `\begin{sloppypar}...\end{sloppypar}` to turn `\sloppy` on for just a part of the document.

Comment: When I click the URLs, they are not forwarded to correct addresses. Any part in the second lines are missing. For Item 1, 2012 is missing. Even worse, For Item 1, 'svn co' is added to the address. Any way to fix it?

Comment: @FEQ - The web address `svn.xxx.ch` that the OP provided (and which I re-used in my answer) isn't active -- and, as far as I can tell, never was. Furthermore, the code in my answer doesn't load the `hyperref` package; hence, any hyperlinks that may exist are provided by the pdf file browser you use rather than by LaTeX and friends. Please clarify what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Mico Thanks! You already gave me an answer! Yes the hyperlink was from my PDF viewer and when I loaded `hyperref`, it went all okay.

Comment: how can I use this if I use pdflatex by default? the urlbreak package states that it will do nothing then. (I could just use latex and dvi->pdf, but I would like a solution for pdflatex)

Comment: @Garonenur - If you use pdflatex and compile directly to pdf, you don't need the `breakurl` package at all. A combination of `\usepackage[hyphens]{url}` in the preamble and `\sloppy` directives (as needed) should do the job.

Comment: @Mico - yes and no, it breaks the links, but doesn't do a very good job, I still get overfull boxes for a link that spans more than one line length. (it can't be shortened in that case.) I just would like to be able to define more breaking chars.

Comment: @Mico I was about to ask my own question and found the answer right below :) `\makeatletter \g@addto@macro{\UrlBreaks}{\do\=\do\$} \makeatother` did it for me.

Comment: @Mico How to get color in url?
I tried
``\usepackage[hyphenbreaks]{breakurl}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,
 linkcolor=black,urlcolor=blue}
`` I can not get result.

Comment: @minhthien_2016 - I believe the `breakurl` package is obsolete by now. When I wrote this answer, back in May 2015, the`xurl` package (so named, presumably, because it's an extension of the `url` package) hadn't been created yet. I think `\usepackage{xurl}` `\usepackage[colorlinks=true,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}` should work. If it does not, then please report any error and warning messages you get. (By the way, a statement such as "I can not get the result" is not actionable.)

Comment: @Mico Thank you very much for your update.

Answer (score 45):

None of the answers helped me out. My long url was placed in a footnote. After searching around I found a working solution [here](https://norwied.wordpress.com/2012/07/10/how-to-break-long-urls-in-bibtex/).

In my preamble:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\def\UrlBreaks{\do\/\do-}
```

The last line instructs the url-package which is loaded with the hyperref-package to additionally break at the characters `/` and `-`. The option `breaklinks=true` in hyperref can be invoked too but for me it had no effect.

Comment: Hi and welcome, how about [Forcing linebreaks in \url](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3033)

Comment: The original post requested line breaks in document text, not `\footnote`s.

Comment: I´m sorry, guys for the not perfectly matching answer. As a justification and a mapping to the real world where search phrases most often not match an exact question title (often because a user doesn´t know the terms yet), a user ends up at not perfectly matching threads. So there is always a chance a non-perfectly-matching answer offers the correct solution to a problem. This is my experience so far `:)`

Comment: it should read `\def\UrlBreaks{\do\/\do\-}`
I needed it to break at = and it would only work with the \ in front of the breaking char.
even better would be
    `\makeatletter
    \g@addto@macro{\UrlBreaks}{\do\/\do\-}
    \makeatother`
so you would not overwrite the original `\UrlBreaks` symbols

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the best answer for this specific answer, or even if it is a very elegant away of doing things, but it fixed my problem with a couple of very long URLs that I had on my .bib files. Thank you very much for the tip.

Answer (score 14):

The problem with **breakurl** package is that it seems incompatible with PDFLaTeX, and XeLaTeX. My colleague Dag Langmyhr pointed out that the **url** package is compatible with **hyperref** if it is loaded before the latter, and consequently

```
\usepackage[T1,hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[colorlinks,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
```

does the job more elegantly (`breaklinks=true` did also not work for me). This approach allows the normal `\url` command to be used when inserting the URLs.

Comment: Dies with "LaTeX Error: Option clash for package url." for me for some reason...

Comment: yes I also get the same error `Option clash for package url. \usepackage`

Answer (score 3):

I think a more current answer is the usage of the package `xurl` as mentioned in this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/407368/48642).

To my understanding the usage of this package frees one from using the command `\sloopy` (since the line break could be almost everywhere).

Comment: Package `xurl` breaks my long urls nicely.

Answer (score 2):

If the other solutions won't work, this was the only solution that worked for me (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53388858/11608761)):

```
% If you want to break on URL numbers
\setcounter{biburlnumpenalty}{9000}
% If you want to break on URL lower case letters
\setcounter{biburllcpenalty}{9000}
% If you want to break on URL UPPER CASE letters
\setcounter{biburlucpenalty}{9000}
```