# Text goes out of bounds

Tags: margins, citing

I am having a problem on the appendix part of my research paper because the text starts to look like this

[image]

The following is the code snippet that generated the line:

```
\bibitem{featureEngineering}
Discover Feature Engineering, How to Engineer Features and How to Get Good at It
\url{http://machinelearningmastery.com/discover-feature-engineering-how-to-engineer-features-and-how-to-get-good-at-it/}. 
(Accessed October 23, 2015)
```

Here is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oldfontcommands]{memoir}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{cite}

\usepackage[
breaklinks=true,colorlinks=true,
%linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,% PDF VIEW
linkcolor=black,urlcolor=black,citecolor=black,% PRINT
bookmarks=true,bookmarksopenlevel=2]{hyperref}

\usepackage{geometry}
% PDF VIEW
% \geometry{total={210mm,297mm},
% left=25mm,right=25mm,%
% bindingoffset=0mm, top=25mm,bottom=25mm}
% PRINT
\geometry{total={210mm,297mm},
left=20mm,right=20mm,
bindingoffset=10mm, top=25mm,bottom=25mm}

\OnehalfSpacing
%\linespread{1.3}

%%% CHAPTER'S STYLE
\chapterstyle{bianchi}
%\chapterstyle{ger}
%\chapterstyle{madsen}
%\chapterstyle{ell}
%%% STYLE OF SECTIONS, SUBSECTIONS, AND SUBSUBSECTIONS
\setsecheadstyle{\Large\bfseries\sffamily\raggedright}
\setsubsecheadstyle{\large\bfseries\sffamily\raggedright}
\setsubsubsecheadstyle{\bfseries\sffamily\raggedright}

\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

%%% STYLE OF PAGES NUMBERING
%\pagestyle{companion}\nouppercaseheads 
%\pagestyle{headings}
%\pagestyle{Ruled}
\pagestyle{plain}
\makepagestyle{plain}
\makeevenfoot{plain}{\thepage}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{plain}{}{}{\thepage}
\makeevenhead{plain}{}{}{}
\makeoddhead{plain}{}{}{}


\maxsecnumdepth{subsection} % chapters, sections, and subsections are numbered
\maxtocdepth{subsection} % chapters, sections, and subsections are in the Table of Contents
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX!  We'd need a code that produces this result to help you.

Comment: You are doing the bibliography by hand, right? Add a manual liebreak. Adding `\usepackage[hyphen]{url}` before loading `hyperref` would also be a good way.

Comment: I made modifications like the one's stated here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54946/how-to-break-long-url-in-an-item Thanks for all your comments.

Comment: the question cited in the op's comment correctly addresses hyphens in long urls, so i am voting to close this as a duplicate.