# Package breakurl Warning: You are using breakurl while processing via pdflatex

Tags: hyperref, urls

I am trying to use `breakurl` package to break long url, so it wraps around, since it is messing the alignment of my table.  The problem is that I keep getting the message

```
Package breakurl Warning: You are using breakurl while processing via pdflatex.
(breakurl)                \burl will be just a synonym of \url.
(breakurl)                 on input line 48.
```

Even though the file is compiled with lualatex. I am following the answer shown [how-to-break-long-url-in-an-item](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54946/how-to-break-long-url-in-an-item) I never used this package before, so I might be doing something wrong, but I do not see it so far.

Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[hyphenbreaks]{breakurl}

\begin{document}
\burl{http://www.google.com}%same error with \url
\end{document}
```

And now

```
lualatex foo.tex 
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.80.0 (TeX Live 2015) (rev 5238)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty))

Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
 ....
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/breakurl/breakurl.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex)))

Package breakurl Warning: You are using breakurl while processing via pdflatex.
(breakurl)                \burl will be just a synonym of \url.
(breakurl)                 on input line 48.
```

My question, why is it saying that pdflatex is used, when the command is lualatex? And what do I need to do to get rid of this error?

Here is the filelist

```
*File List*
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size11.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
hyperref.sty    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Construct package bundles (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
  ifvtex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2007/09/27 v1.1 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
luatex-loader.sty    2010/03/09 v0.4 Lua module loader (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2011/11/25 v1.13 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2012/04/08 v1.3 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  bitset.sty    2011/01/30 v1.1 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2011/01/30 v1.2 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2010/09/02 v1.4 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2012/05/28 v1.2 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2011/01/30 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2011/06/30 v1.8 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2011/10/05 v1.16 At begin shipout hook (HO)
refcount.sty    2011/10/16 v3.4 Data extraction from label references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2011/01/30 v1.7 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
 auxhook.sty    2011/03/04 v1.3 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
 hpdftex.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
rerunfilecheck.sty    2011/04/15 v1.7 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
breakurl.sty    2013/04/10 v1.40 Breakable hyperref URLs
 xkeyval.sty    2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
 nameref.sty    2012/10/27 v2.43 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2010/12/03 v1.4 Cleanup title references (HO)
     foo.out
     foo.out
  t1cmtt.fd    2014/09/29 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
 ***********
```

reference https://www.ctan.org/pkg/breakurl?lang=en

Comment: thanks @DavidCarlisle I removed the fontenc and inputenc,

Comment: remove breakurl as well, and you are done:-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Luatex 0.80 is compatible with pdflatex so uses the same back end files for most driver-specific functions. As your log shows:

```
 (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
```

The pdftex hyperef file is used.

To avoid the warning simply do not use the package, it is not needed, and does nothing very useful, for pdftex or luatex.

For luatex you should also avoid inputenc and fontenc packages.

Comment: how should one suppress hyperref's desire to load hpdftex.def?  (on Overleaf, I cannot simply delete it, either.)