# How to get rid of breakurl warning?

Tags: pdftex, urls

How do I get rid of this warning:

> "Package breakurl Warning: You are using breakurl while processing via pdflatex.(breakurl) \burl  will be just a synonym of \url. on input line 48."

Why do I care? The journal we're submitting to states there should no latex warnings.

Context: I'm on Overleaf. There are some urls. I'm not calling the function burl (nor using packages hyperref/breakurl).

What I've tried:

- Looked into the source code (https://texdoc.org/serve/breakurl.pdf/0) - the code that causes it is on page 6.
- Tried to figure out if I can "not use" a package so it wouldn't try to load burl (looked into this but not sure relevant: [How to NOT include a package in a TeX file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/424825/how-to-not-include-a-package-in-a-tex-file))
- Looked into other breakurl errors (e.g., [Package breakurl Warning: You are using breakurl while processing via pdflatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279402/package-breakurl-warning-you-are-using-breakurl-while-processing-via-pdflatex)) but couldn't find one that addressed this question.
- Loaded the two relevant packages directly: \usepackage{hyperref} \usepackage{breakurl}

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Can you tell from the log file whether `breakurl` is being loaded? If so, can you identify the package that is doing it?

Comment: why can't you avoid to load breakurl? (It is not needed)

Comment: @JohnPalmieri: Yes, if I put \listfiles in the preamble, breakurl does show up in the *file list* portion of the log. I'm not sure what's calling it. I'll keep looking.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: that would be great. I don't currently know how. I'm not calling it directly, but perhaps I can remove/adjust the package that's calling it

Comment: If I look for `\RequirePackage{breakurl}` in my TeX distribution, I see these packages (may not be a complete list): `FUpowerdot.cls`, `tui.cls`, `abntex2cite.sty`, `pst-doc.cls`, `cclayout.sty`.

Comment: Aha - it looks like the journal template calls it: \RequirePackage{hyperref}%
%%\RequirePackage{hypcap}%
\gdef\breakurldefns{%
\if@pdflatex\else%
  \RequirePackage[hyphenbreaks]{breakurl}%
  \let\href\burlalt%
\fi}%
\breakurldefns%

Comment: Does that mean we'll just be stuck with the warning? [Or should I pursue turning it off further?]

Comment: well you can suppress the loading. Add `\makeatletter
\@namedef{ver@breakurl.sty}{}\makeatother` at the begin of your document.

Comment: Thank you both!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My bet is that you're using some Springer Nature class.

The (scanty) documentation doesn't tell it, but if you want to avoid that warning you need to pass the class the option `pdflatex`.

**Example 1**

```
\documentclass{sn-jnl}

\begin{document}

\title{Test}
\author{Test}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

In the log file you get

```
Package breakurl Warning: You are using breakurl while processing via pdflatex.
(breakurl)                \burl will be just a synonym of \url.
(breakurl)                 on input line 48.
```

**Example 2**

```
\documentclass[pdflatex]{sn-jnl}

\begin{document}

\title{Test}
\author{Test}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

No warning in the log file.

**Other classes**

If you're not with a Springer Nature class, add

```
\makeatletter
\disable@package@load{burl}{}
\makeatother
```

at the very beginning of your file, before the `\documentclass` line.

Comment: I am indeed. Thank you!! The full command (for future readers) was: \documentclass[sn-mathphys, pdflatex]{sn-jnl}