# Hyperref linebreak in moderncv documentclass

Tags: hyperref, line-breaking, moderncv, urls

I am using

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\newcommand{\MYhref}[3][blue]{\href{#2}{\color{#1}{#3}}}
```

for one of my links, I am using:

```
\cventry{MSc THESIS}{``Title here''}{}{}{}{\begin{itemize}
\item Link to article: 
\MYhref{https://www.researchgate.net/publication/title_here}
{www.researchgate.net/publication/title\_here}
\end{itemize}
```

However, here the link to the article appears in blue as expected, but the 
link goes beyond the margin (part of the link not being visible). **I would 
like to break the link into two lines.**

I tried using the solutions provided in 
[this tex.stackexchange link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54946/how-to-break-long-url-in-an-item) and [this tex.stackexchange link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3033/forcing-linebreaks-in-url) to 
no avail. 
When I try

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}\usepackage{hyperref}
```

I get an error stating

```
! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package hyperref.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several hours of Googling, I found an answer to my question.

Just by using:

```
\MYhref{https://www.researchgate.net/publication/title_here}
{\nolinkurl{www.researchgate.net/publication/title\_here}}
```

by using the option `\nolinkurl{}`, latex automatically breaks the link.