# URL in list of figures

Tags: table-of-contents, line-breaking, urls

My usual image snippet looks like this:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{images/image_name}
        \caption[Capture in list of figures]{Capture below image}
    \end{center}
\end{figure}
```

However, I have to provide the source URL in the list of figures too, so somehing like this would be nice, which sadly, does not work:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{images/image_name}
        \caption[Capture in list of figures (Source: https://a.b.c/xyz.pdf (accessed on 29.1.2018))]{Capture below image}
    \end{center}
\end{figure}
```

How can this be realised in LaTeX?

Comment: `hyperref` or `url` package and `\url` macro ;-) ?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer This is a step into the right direction. The problem is that it goes further right than it should, as, naturally, urls tend to be quite long...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I solved the 'no-line-break' problem by combining https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/254734/153714 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10401/153714. Thank you!