# Longtable Long Word wrapping issue

Tags: line-breaking, longtable, hyphenation

Im trying to wrap long words in a longtable and its not quite working right. some of the words spill over to the next cell. any help would be great thanks!

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[left=65pt,top=28pt,right=65pt,bottom=65pt]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{longtable}% http://ctan.org/pkg/longtable
\usepackage{seqsplit}% http://ctan.org/pkg/seqsplit
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{m{50pt} | m{360pt} | m{50pt}}
  & \seqsplit{thisisareallylongexamplethisisareallylongexamplethisisareallylongexamplethisisareallylongexample with a space} & test1 \\
  & \seqsplit{thisisareallylongexamplethisisareallylongexamplethisisareallylongexamplethisisareallylongexample\ with\ a\ space} & test2 \\
  & \seqsplit{thisisareallylongexamplethisisareallylongexamplethisisareallylongexamplethisisareallylongexample~with~a~space} & test3 \\
  \hline
  klhd ldgdddddddksjd fkldjs fldjs fkldjs lfkj sdlkf jlksjdf lkdsj fkldsj fkldsj fkldsj fklj sfkljds fdfdfdfdgddddddhghgghghdflkj & kjshfd ksj fdkjshf kjds hfkdjs hfkjds h &
    jsdh kkjhdskkjsfhhdsfhjdsfh dskj dkjshf dskjjkhs hjsd kjfkdshf kjdsh  
  \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well there's your problem. How should that word be broken across the line when it doesn't fit? Moreover, there is no hyphenation pattern for `fdfdfdfdgddddddhghgghghdflkj`.

Comment: Should it not know when to break the word and were? This report is dynamically generated, these words could be anything of any size. Thanks

Comment: there might be something useful in this: [Wrapping long lines that contain no spaces](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6171/579)

Comment: why do you use `\seqsplit` in the second column but not the first?

Comment: If that word forms part of a regular language, then you can load that language's [`babel`](http://ctan.org/pkg/babel), which should include hyphenation patterns. However, if the word doesn't exist with a hyphenation pattern, certain assumptions are made and it may be broken at the wrong point.

Comment: i was just playing around with \seqspilt, and it does not add hyphenation when it breaks a word. i would like to get this working with the length of the word...if the length is greater then the cell width, break it. something tells me this is not something simple :P

Comment: @SteveM are your real examples words in some language (there are hyphenation tables for most) or are they really just random strings, in which case something like seqsplit is what you want

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the hyphenation patterns for English do not help here. That's the problem `seqsplit` is trying to fix, but you are not using it in all the cell.

[image]

Note it is unrelated to `longtable` you would get the same behavior in a paragraph on the main page.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[left=65pt,top=28pt,right=65pt,bottom=65pt]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{longtable}% http://ctan.org/pkg/longtable
\usepackage{seqsplit}% http://ctan.org/pkg/seqsplit
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{m{50pt} | m{360pt} | m{50pt}}
  & \seqsplit{thisisareallylongexamplethisisareallylongexamplethisisareallylongexamplethisisareallylongexample with a space} & test1 \\
  & \seqsplit{thisisareallylongexamplethisisareallylongexamplethisisareallylongexamplethisisareallylongexample\ with\ a\ space} & test2 \\
  & \seqsplit{thisisareallylongexamplethisisareallylongexamplethisisareallylongexamplethisisareallylongexample~with~a~space} & test3 \\
  \hline\obeyspaces\seqsplit{klhd ldgdddddddksjd fkldjs fldjs fkldjs lfkj sdlkf jlksjdf lkdsj fkldsj fkldsj fkldsj fklj sfkljds fdfdfdfdgddddddhghgghghdflkj} & 
\obeyspaces\seqsplit{kjshfd ksj fdkjshf kjds hfkdjs hfkjds h}&
\obeyspaces\seqsplit{jsdh kkjhdskkjsfhhdsfhjdsfh dskj dkjshf dskjjkhs hjsd kjfkdshf kjdsh}\\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

If you want hyphenation, add

```
 \def\seqinsert{\-}
```

before the table

Comment: Thanks for your help, seqsplit does work, but how to add hyphen when the word breaks?

Comment: @SteveM I just added that in an updated answer (I have never used `seqsplit` before, I just went `texdoc seqsplit` and did what it said:-)

Comment: Thanks! this seems to be working. and the \obeyspaces is a nice little trick!