# Linebreak inside multicolumn

Tags: tables, longtable, multicolumn

I have the following problem I want to create a table that use a `\multicolumn`, I want the following

[image: eg 1]

but I have this.

[image: eg 1]

This is the code that I'm using, Does anyone know how to do this?

```
\begin{longtable}{| p{5cm} | p{5cm} | p{5cm} |} 
\hline 
Número & Compuesto & Primo \\ 
\hline
124 & X & - \\ 
\hline 
\multicolumn{3}{ p{15cm} }{167149925598414533584400563496249196484626567023954743572719464788289404566848180320469925318728110574074739762450403911375568454294210806669447761437579390493214133578688918826283772069691256544127325402936461605210931966803891178446234431626664000699233882131687123515785136485929356311218831711685861511    }\\
\hline
\end{longtable}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Perhaps the `seqsplit` package can help, see [Wrapping long lines that contain no spaces](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6234)

Comment: Is LaTeX supposed to determine the three line break points on its own (if so, how?), or do you plan to provide explicit guidance?

Comment: I want that Latex determine the line breaks, it is not necesary three .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not caused by the table or `multicol` but simply by the fact that LaTeX doesn't know how to split the extremely long number you gave it. I suggest using the package `seqsplit`, designed for typesetting DNA sequences.

```
\usepackage{seqsplit}

...

\begin{longtable}{| p{5cm} | p{5cm} | p{5cm} |} 
\hline 
Número & Compuesto & Primo \\ 
\hline
124 & X & - \\ 
\hline 
\multicolumn{3}{| p{15cm} |}
{\seqsplit{167149925598414533584400563496249196484626567023954743572719464788289404566848180320469925318728110574074739762450403911375568454294210806669447761437579390493214133578688918826283772069691256544127325402936461605210931966803891178446234431626664000699233882131687123515785136485929356311218831711685861511}}\\
\hline
\end{longtable}
```

[image]